# Возможно ли произвести безопасное извлечение USB?

Tags: c++, python-3.x

В задании просится написать программу, которая может находить подключенные USB устройства и безопасно их отключать.

Я искал такую возможность на Python 3 и C++, но ничего, кроме отключение самого порта, не находил.

Нужно, чтобы происходило безопасное отключение USB устройства, но сам порт продолжал работать.

Comment: По вашей теме https://stackoverflow.com/q/85649/5909792

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться)